# UIAlertView button in action issue

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have declared the `UIAlertViewDelegate` to call its methods like this way

```
-(IBAction)hidding{
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    UIAlertView *alert1= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in"
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcomes you"]
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert1 show];
}


- (void)alertViewUIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndexNSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    NSLog(@"clicking");
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

To check which button is clicked and perform some action. However When the `UIAlertView` appears and when I click on OK option it crashes and gives me the error of *"Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"*.

To be more specific I've declared this `UIAlertView` in *1stclass* and then i'm comparing some parameteres in *2ndclass* and from *2ndclass* it is calling the *1stclass* method which has this `UIAlertView`.

Comment: No memory management? Are you using ARC?

Comment: please tell us more specific detail error. Try to use breakpoint tools for tracking your error code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the ARC and yes I have tracked the code using the breakpoints and I noticed that the execution is coming to that point aswell but it is not performing the desired action. Whenever I pass the controlflow to appdelegate from oneclass and again back to oneclass from appdelegate it gives me this issue of I cannot call any property or anymethod which will execute on oneclass nib file or within itself.when I put some button on oneclass xib to hidden based on appdelegate class(conditional flow back to oneclass) while debugging i noticed comes to that line but performs no action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I used and confirm it However Got the solution, it was like I had to create the @protocol class and declare the -(void)methods in it and then create a delegate in Appdelegate class for it, and also in oneclass. So, I called the @protocol class method and in turn it calls the oneclass method, NOTE: I inherited the @protocol method in oneclass and the issue got resolved.
Here is the complete code for the solution this is the @protocol.h class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SMLoginDelegate 

- (void)didDisconnection;
@end

This is my oneclass

#import "oneclass.h"

@interface oneclass : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,SMLoginDelegate>
{


}
@end

oneclass.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     AppDelegate *del1 = [self appDelegate];
    del1._loginDelegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


appdelegate.h class
@interface FirstphaseAppDelegate {
__weak NSObject <SMLoginDelegate> *_loginDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id _loginDelegate;

appdelegate.m class

@synthesize _loginDelegate;

-(void)anymethod
{
[_loginDelegate didDisconnection];
}
```

Comment: hope this will help others too!.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)alertViewUIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndexNSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    NSLog(@"clicking");
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

That method looks extremely weird to me. Should be like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    NSLog(@"clicking");
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

you messed up the method name....

Comment: Alright however I'm stuck at the same point of my main function. Whenever I pass the controlflow to appdelegate from oneclass and again back to oneclass from appdelegate it gives me this issue of I cannot call any property or anymethod which will execute on oneclass nib file or within itself.For example the alertview crashes again by "-[__NSCFString alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b2c520" or even if I put some button from to hidden on oneclass from appdelegate class it doesn't perform that function though while debugging i noticed comes to that line.

Comment: have you conformed to the UIAlertViewDelegate?

Comment: Yep.... did I help you?
Im not so sure then what the problem could be...
Maybe over releasing or under retaining

Comment: i also noticed you posted the same thing on the iPhone dev forum... did that work out for you?

Comment: No, it did not work for me however I worked around and got the solution for it.

Comment: I was posting the solution, however i'll have to wait for other 4 hours to post the answer.

Comment: oh great! Good to see u thinking!! :)